# How can I see udev actions at runtime?

Tags: udev

Does there exist a `udev` command that allows me to see in real time (at run time) on the terminal the creation of the device node when newly device is attached?

A little bit as happens when using the tail command to visualize the log: `tail -f /var/log/syslog`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is but a direct one (not from any log).

```
sudo udevadm monitor
```

or for cleaner output only from udev:

```
sudo udevadm monitor -u
```

**Reference: [`man udevadm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/udevadm.8.html)**:

```
udevadm monitor [options]
   Listens to the kernel uevents and events sent out by a udev rule and
   prints the devpath of the event to the console. It can be used to
   analyze the event timing, by comparing the timestamps of the kernel
   uevent and the udev event.

   -u, --udev
       Print the udev event after the rule processing.
```